# timestamp data type can not store some date format

Tags: php, mysql

Timestamp data type cannot take  or store this date format  “ Thursday 17th of January 2013 at 11:47:49 AM “ yet this is the format I would like to store in the db because the client likes that format . I can store it using varchar or text but those data types cannot allow me make some  minutes calculations using TIMESTAMPDIFF function  . any help please :

Comment: Why does the client care what the format is in the database? You can convert to whatever format they like before displaying the dates. And did you consider the `DATETIME` type?

Comment: You will have timezone and DST issues. Better store UTC timestamps in database using unix timestamps (INT), ISO8601 (2013-01-17T19:47:49Z) or DATETIME (make sure you configure everything UTC). Only when displaying a date or timestamp just convert to whatever timezone and formatting you want. If the only interface is a browser, just use javascript's Date object to convert to the local time (in whatever format you like).

Comment: # function to get right time 
    date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Johannesburg');
    function time_diff_conv($start, $s)
    {
        $string="";
        $t = array( //suffixes
            'd' => 86400,
            'h' => 3600,
            'm' => 60,
        );
        $s = abs($s - $start);
        foreach($t as $key => &$val) {
            $$key = floor($s/$val);
            $s -= ($$key*$val);
            $string .= ($$key==0) ? '' : $$key . "$key ";
        }
        return $string . $s. 's';
    }

 $date = date('l jS \of F Y \a\t h:i:s A')."\n";

 # function to get right time

Comment: Thats the function I use to get time to store in the db coz its grabbing the right time : and i store it as text: now i get a problem if I wanna calculate 24 hours or more using time stamp : I guess u can get me clearly

Answer (score 0):

The format stored is a real, the format you want to show must be computed from there on.

Here is a little sample : http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/php_date_time.php

Answer (score 0):

If you want that format only, change data type of the field to VARCHAR, but it would be better to store it as DATETIME/TIMESTAMP and then while display you can user DATE format of php to show it the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

**The storing problem you described can be solved by  using unix timestamps (INT), ISO8601 (2013-01-17T19:47:49Z) or DATETIME (make sure you configure everything UTC) instead of that long string which is hard to decode without running into timezone and DST issues.**

Only when displaying a date or timestamp in a interface just convert to whatever timezone and formatting you want. If the only interface is a browser, just use javascript's Date object to convert to the local time (in whatever format you like).

MySQL query examples:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`datetime_stsuff`) FROM `whatever` LIMIT 1
```

or

```
SELECT `int_unixtimestamp_seconds` FROM `whatever` LIMIT 1
```

Javascript examples:

```
var objDateFromDatabase=new Date(<?php echo json_encode($nUnixTimestampFromDB);?>*1000);
```

or

```
//note that older browsers don't support the Z suffix ("Zulu time" (GMT or UTC)) so use +00:00 instead (2012-01-01T12:34:56+00:00).
var objDateFromDatabase=new Date(<?php echo json_encode($strISO8601TimestampFromDB);?>*1000);
```

See the [MDN Date object docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for what methods you can use to format to your clients desire. The methods which don't contain the keyword UTC return values already converted to the browser's timezone (OS configured timezone), so you don't have to bother to ask user's for their timezones.

Answer (score 0):

You should store timastamp value as is - TIMESTAMP format.

Use [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function to format values, for example -

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(column1, '%W %M %Y') FROM table1;
```